# Hide Facebook News tab "New for you" red notification badges

Tags: facebook, notifications, facebook-notifications, news-feed

Whenever I open the Facebook website on a desktop browser, I see an obnoxious notification badge on the "News" tab icon:

[image: Facebook News tab notification]

This badge counts the "New for you" news stories, that I definitely don't want to see or be notified about.

[image: Facebook New for you]

Clicking "See all (5)" shows you even more awful stories:

[image: Facebook News]

I have never seen this News badge on the mobile app, so it appears to be on the Desktop website only.

How can I hide the red notification badge? There is seemingly no "Settings" button to control this notification badge, that I can find.

I never signed up for these news sources. I never want to see this badge. How can I hide the red dot and/or the entire News tab?